# Java lambda aggregator

Tags: java, lambda

I have a list

PLANS:

```
ID,    A_CODE, COMPARTMENT
10683   163     213 
10683   616     194
10683   163     212
10683   163     211
10683   163     214
```

and want to produce
AGGREGATED_PLANS

```
ID      A_CODE  COMPARTMENTS
10683   163     211/212/213/214
10683   616     194
```

How can I do this using java lambda expression ?

I am thinking something like this, but not sure about the aggregateCompartments part ?

```
plans.stream()
     .collect(groupingBy(Plan::getACode, 
           aggregateCompartments(Plan::getCompartments)));
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Please update your question with a
[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Does using `groupingBy(Plan::getACode,
                                              mapping(Plan::getCompartments, joining("/"))`, help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this may help you:

```
    List<Plan> plans = new ArrayList<>();
    plans.add(new Plan("10683", "163", "213"));
    plans.add(new Plan("10683", "616", "194"));
    plans.add(new Plan("10683", "163", "212"));
    plans.add(new Plan("10683", "163", "211"));
    plans.add(new Plan("10683", "163", "214"));

    System.out.println(
        plans.stream().collect(
               Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.id + " " + p.aCode, 
               Collectors.mapping(Plan::getCompartment, Collectors.joining("/")))));
```

output:

```
{10683 616=194, 10683 163=213/212/211/214}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I get you right, your desired output is a collection of plans, where `compartment` field of each plan is aggregated from all grouped compartments.

In this case I suggest you to use a `toMap` collector, which has a special `mergeFunction` argument:

```
Collection<Plan> aggregatedPlans = plans
    .stream()
    .collect(toMap(
            Plan::getACode,
            p -> new Plan(p.getId(), p.getACode(), p.getCompartment()),
            (p1, p2) -> {
                p1.compartment += "/" + p2.compartment;
                return p1;
            }))
    .values();
```

If you add the following two methods to your `Plan` object

```
public Plan clone() {
    return new Plan(id, aCode, compartment);
}

public Plan merge(Plan other) {
    compartment += "/" + other.compartment;
    return this;
}
```

then the code can be simplified like this:

```
Collection<Plan> aggregatedPlans = plans.stream()
            .collect(toMap(Plan::getACode, Plan::clone, Plan::merge)).values();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to grupo by `A_CODE`:

```
Map<ACodeType, Set<CompartmentType>> result = plans.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Plan::getACode, 
        Collectors.mapping(
            Plan::getCompartments, 
            Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new))));
```

This groups by `A_CODE`, with a downstream collector that first adapts each plan to its compartment and then collects each adapted group to a `TreeSet`, to maintain the compartments sorted and without duplicates. This needs the type of the compartment to be `Comparable`. If it's not, you'd need to provide a `Comparator` to the `TreeSet`'s constructor.